# Where is KeePass2 plugins directory?

Tags: directory, keepass

Where is the **KeePass2** plugins directory?
I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`/usr/lib/keepass2` or `/usr/lib/keepass2/plugins`

Comment: For others who run into this: you may need to `sudo apt-get install mono-complete` before plugins will actually be considered "valid" by KeePass2. This is *not* mentioned on their website, but it is required for KeePass2 to compile the plugins to a native format.

Comment: Is there no way to install it in the user's home directory?

Comment: Error on Keepass Mono for Ubuntu with GoogleSyncPlugin: "The plugin cannot be loaded" https://sourceforge.net/p/kp-googlesync/discussion/general/thread/899c770e/?limit=25

Comment: mono-complete does work with the KeePassRC plugin for the Kee browser extension. See more info here: "KeePass and Ubuntu 20.04 Setup (with Chrome, Firefox)?" https://askubuntu.com/questions/1228389/keepass-and-ubuntu-20-04-setup-with-chrome-firefox

Comment: This may help greatly with KP plugins on Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1228389/keepass-and-ubuntu-2020-setup-with-chrome-firefox